# serialise bool? error reflecting type

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

i have a class like

```
   [Serializable]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool myBool { get; set; }
    }
```

But this serializes the value of the bool to false when the attribute is not present in the xml.
When the attribute is not in the xml I want the property to be null.

So i tried this

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool? myBool { get; set; }
}
```

But then the serializer errors

```
Type t = Type.GetType("Assembly.NameSpace.MyClass");
                XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(t); //error "There was an error reflecting type"
```

Please give me a example of i can do this. I know there are some related questions on SO but nothing that shows how to overcome the reflection error with a nullable bool. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the "*Specified" field pattern to control this (see "Controlling Generated XML" on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-xml-serialization-xmlserializer#control-generated-xml)):

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool myBool { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool myBoolSpecified;
}
```

The logic now becomes:

- If `!myBoolSpecified`, then `myBool` is logically `null`
- Else use the `true` or `false` of `myBool`

Comment: @Aliostad: I appreciate the merits of your approach, but if the XML structure is not open to modification it will not work while this one will.

Comment: this looks great but doesnt seem to work. Is the '{}Specified' a magic name? do I need some logic in the getter?

Comment: @Jules: Yes, it's a magic name. Search for "The pattern is created in the form of propertyNameSpecified" on the linked page. If it doesn't work please show your current code.

Comment: I have a problem with this. Whilst it does leave out the attribute when deserialising it doesnt serialise the property to an attribute when the property has a value. I need the solution to work in both directions.

Comment: @Jules: I 'm not sure what you mean. What's the value of both the property and the field when you serialize?

Comment: I have a real problem with this as well. This is a major in the serializer. So, we can serialize nullable integers, but we can't serialize nullable bools? Madness.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this](http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/post/2010/06/11/How-to-serializedeserialize-a-nullable-date.aspx) for information regarding dealing with nullable fields and XML attributes. There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295697/deserializing-empty-xml-attribute-value-into-nullable-int-property-using-xmlseri) here too. Basically the serializer cannot handle an XML attribute field defined as nullable, but there is a work-around.

I.e 2 properties, one which contains the nullable (not XML stored), and the other which is used in the read/writing (XML attribute stored as a string). Perhaps this might be what you need?

```
private bool? _myBool;
[XmlIgnore]
public bool? MyBool
{
    get
    {
        return _myBool;
    }
    set
    {
        _myBool = value;
    }
}

[XmlAttribute("MyBool")]
public string MyBoolstring
{
    get
    {
        return MyBool.HasValue
        ? XmlConvert.ToString(MyBool.Value)
        : string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        MyBool =
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
        ? XmlConvert.ToBoolean(value)
        : (bool?)null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a **nullable type has to be defined as an element (which is default) and not Attribute.**

Reason is when the value is null, it can be represented as `<mybool xs:nil="true"/>` as such **cannot be represented as attribute**.

Have a look at this snippet:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    // removed the attribute!!!
    public bool? myBool { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
var stream = new MemoryStream();
serializer.Serialize(stream, new MyClass(){myBool = null});
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray()));
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.o
rg/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <myBool xsi:nil="true" /> <!-- NOTE HERE !!! -->
</MyClass>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is attribute in the xml I receive so I cant control that. Is there any way to have a nullable bool attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable.aspx)**:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public bool? myBool { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is only workable when you can choose to instead serialise as an element, instead of an attribute