# When xml element is empty, XmlSerializer throw exception

Tags: c#

When xml element is empty, XmlSerializer throw exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing empty xml attribute value into nullable int property using XmlSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295697/deserializing-empty-xml-attribute-value-into-nullable-int-property-using-xmlseri)

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

at the beginning of the xml file.

Comment: This won't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `<StartRange></StartRange>` isn't 'null'/'nil', it's an empty string. An empty string isn't a valid integer - hence the error.

You either need to change the XML to add the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute or change the definition to use a `string` for those properties (and parse them after the fact).

Comment: @ShreyanshMakwana You can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295697/deserializing-empty-xml-attribute-value-into-nullable-int-property-using-xmlseri) for the available options. I don't think you do what you want without some sort of workaround.