# How to deserialize element name as string prop

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

How to deserialize "Valid" as text to be populated on `Data.Valid` property.

In below code, Id is populated correctly, but "Data.Valid" is always populated as NULL (reason should be as its always empty element but, I need this prop name `Valid` to be populated under `Data.Valid` ).

Input XML:

```xml
<Data>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <Valid />
</Data>
```

Trying to deserialize like this:

```
using (StringReader xreader = new StringReader(xml))
{
   return (T)xmlSerial.Deserialize(xreader);
}

public class Data
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Valid {get;set;} //unable to hold string value "Valid".  Also tried by making separate class as "valid". 
}
```

Comment: Valid has no value in your input XML so when it is deserialized there is no value to hold in the model. Valid in your XML data model is just an attribute with no value

Comment: Does this help? ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412741/how-to-handle-self-closed-tags-issue-while-xml-deserialize-in-c-sharp

Comment: @NeilW Yes, that solved the problem. Thanks.