# XML deserialization returns list with one empty item

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, deserialization

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
<accounts>
    <items>
        <account>
            <voornaam><FirstName</voornaam>
            <naam>LastName</naam>
            <gebruikersnaam>Username</gebruikersnaam>
            <internnummer></internnummer>
            <klasnummer></klasnummer>
        </account>
    </items>
</accounts>
```

With these classes:

```cs
public class Accounts
{
   public Accounts()
   {
      items = new List<Account>();
   }

   [XmlElement]
   public List<Account> items { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
   public string voornaam { get; set; }
   public string naam { get; set; }
   public string gebruikersnaam { get; set; }
   public int? internnummer { get; set; }
   public int? klasnummer { get; set; }
}
```

And this code:

```cs
var decoded = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><accounts><items><account><voornaam>FirstName</voornaam><naam>LastName</naam><gebruikersnaam></gebruikersnaam><internnummer></internnummer><klasnummer></klasnummer></account></items></accounts>";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Accounts), new XmlRootAttribute("accounts"));
StringReader reader = new StringReader(decoded);
var accounts = (Accounts)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

All I get from this is an `Accounts` instance with the property `Items` containing one `Account` instance with every property `null`.

Comment: Aside from the given answer, I would recommend, as my personal opinion on the matter, to use another type of serialization, like JSON or something. XML is outdated and horrible to work with, lol...

Comment: @JuanR I would, but I get this data from a SOAP-webservice so not much I can do about it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the `items` as XML array with `XmlArrayAttribute` and also with the `XmlArrayItemAttribute` with (element) item's name: "account" and as `Account` type. [`XmlArrayAttribute` Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute?view=net-6.0#examples).

```cs
public class Accounts
{
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName= "account",
           Type = typeof(Account))]
    [XmlArray(ElementName="items")]
    public List<Account> items { get; set; }
}
```

Meanwhile, suggest using `XmlElementAttribute` to specify the element name in XML instead of naming the properties as camelCase.

For the reason why need `InternnummerText` and `KlasnummerText` properties you can refer to the question: [Deserializing empty xml attribute value into nullable int property using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1479195/8017690) (will not cover in this answer).

```cs
public class Accounts
{
    public Accounts()
    {
        Items = new List<Account>();
    }

    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName= "account",
           Type = typeof(Account))]
    [XmlArray(ElementName="items")]
    public List<Account> Items { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="account")]
public class Account
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int? Klasnummer { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int? Internnummer { get; set; }
    
    [XmlElement(ElementName="voornaam")]
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="naam")]
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="gebruikersnaam")]
    public string Gebruikersnaam { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="internnummer")]
    public string InternnummerText 
    {
      get { return (Internnummer.HasValue) ? Internnummer.ToString() : null; } 
      set { Internnummer = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? int.Parse(value) : default(int?); }
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="klasnummer")]
    public string KlasnummerText 
    {
      get { return (Klasnummer.HasValue) ? Klasnummer.ToString() : null; } 
      set { Klasnummer = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? int.Parse(value) : default(int?); }
    }
}
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vevcTm)