# Can XmlSerializer deserialize into a Nullable<int>?

Tags: asp.net, xml-serialization

This is duplicate of [Can XmlSerializer deserialize into a Nullable<int>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306877/can-xmlserializer-deserialize-into-a-nullableint) but I need a solution that neither change xml document nor forces me to implement IXmlSerializable interface. I dont want to implement IXmlSerializable because I have many additional elements beside `<number`> that get deserialized correctly.

My xml can contain either element `<number>4</number>` or `<number/>`

```
<root>
...
either <number>4</number> or <number/>
... [other elements]
</root>
```

Class

```
public class root
{
public int? number {get; set;}
...
}
```

does not work.

Comment: What version are you using? I made a similar class and the output was <number xs:nil="true" />

Comment: Yep, that works.  If you can't tolerate the xs:nil="true" , you need to take some alternative steps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use a surrogate property.

```
public class MyType1
{
    // XmlIgnore means it is not directly serialized
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int? number
    {
        get; set;
    }

    // acts as a surrogate for the nullable property
    [XmlElement("number")]
    public string _number_Surrogate
    {
        get
        {
            return (number.HasValue) ? number.ToString() : "";
        }
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(""))
            {
                number = Int32.Parse(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public System.DateTime Time
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bit of a hassle am I right? See my comment above.

Comment: Yeah, it's a hassle, but sometimes it's necessary.  If you want `<number/>`, and not `<number xs:nil='true'/>`, then you need to do extra work.

Answer (score -2):

You could always do a string replace on the final xml output.

```
Replace(" i:nil=\"true\"/>","/>");
```

Generally, it is a bad idea to try to hack at xml with string manipulation, but the replace above is safe and will always convert `<anything i:nil="true"/>` to `<anything/>`.

It's a hack, but an acceptable one considering the alternative.

Comment: -1: what if a different prefix is used for the namespace that "nil" is in? What if the namespace declaration happens to be present on that element?