# Deserialize XML with optional tags

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have an XML with an optional tag as follows:

```
<Config>
    <CheckForCompleteTransform>true</CheckForCompleteTransform>
    <!-- more tags -->
</Config>
```

And the class-definition:

```
public class config {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("CheckForCompleteTransform")]
    public bool? CheckForCompleteTransform { get; set; }
}
```

This works if I either set the tag to what I provided within my example-XML above or I omit it completely. But what if I provide the tag as `<MyTag/>`? If this notation is used I want the serializer to set the corresponding property within my class to true, but I awlays get a

> System.FormatException: the string literal '' is not valid for type
>   Boolean

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't verified this myself, but have you tried adding a

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
```

attribute to the CheckForCompleteTransform ?

EDIT:

Ok, how about together with

```
DefaultValueAttribute(true);
```

Comment: Still the same exception: "string literal '' is no valid value for type Boolean"

Answer (score 2):

Check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306877/can-xmlserializer-deserialize-into-a-nullableint)

u can use *[XmlElement("CheckForCompleteTransform", IsNullable=true)]* CheckForCompleteTransform property in your class

```
public class config
    {
        [XmlElement("CheckForCompleteTransform", IsNullable = true)]
        public bool? CheckForCompleteTransform { get; set; }
    }
```

and add **xsi:nil="true"** attribute to CheckForCompleteTransform tag like this

```
<CheckForCompleteTransform xsi:nil="true" />
```

Comment: This works, although I cannot change the actual XML (only for development-purposes I have control on it:( the actual XML is generated by 3rd party and therefor not modifyable)