# make XmlElement optional in c#

Tags: c#, xml, rest

I use REST (XML) for client-server communication.
The given example should be read from my Channel.

```
[XmlRoot("Device")]
public class RestDevice
{
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to make the XmlElement "type" optional (so that if the root doesn't contain one, I will get null as the Type property of class RestDevice.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for [minOccurs="0"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zds0b35c.aspx)? It looks like the attribute should be `[XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]`. (untested)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize XML with optional tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867210/deserialize-xml-with-optional-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "type", IsNullable = true)]
public string Type;
```

Is what you are looking for.

Comment: Generate `<type xsi:nil="true" />`, but if I want ***not generate NOTHING*** for _element type_

Comment: @Kiquenet Leave out `IsNullable = true` from the attribute to have the element absent from the xml when the value is null.