# How to deserialize an XML file containing an \u0000 using XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer, xmlreader

I have a problem about XmlSerializer. In my huge XML file, there are some Null characters (\u0000) and so XmlSerializer (Deserializer) gives me an error. I found out that I need to set Normalization to false (via: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx), so I tried this:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
reader.Normalization = false;
return (T)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

I tried also second possibility, when I used XmlReader, because is also suggested by MSDN, and I tried to set CheckCharacters to false like this:

```
 XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
 XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings() { CheckCharacters = false }; 
 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename, settings))
 {
       return (T)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
 }
```

`

but both solutions give me the same result: InvalidOperationException on the line and column in XML where is the Null character.

Could you please give me an advice about that? I need to "load" the XML structure to my defined class. Without lines with these characters its working fine.

Thanks! :)

**Edit:** I forgot to say, that I've tried to load the content to a string and update the string, but inserted content is to big, so I get System.OutOfMemoryException and if I try to parse the file line by line, it's too slow. :(

Comment: this may be helpful..   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306877/can-xmlserializer-deserialize-into-a-nullableint

Comment: Or, more likely, [Escape invalid XML characters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17735649).

Comment: Thanks! But all of these methods are based on loading the content to a string, but I have really huge file, so I get System.OutOfMemoryException. I tried this before. And if I try this with parsing it by line, it's to slow for my use. :(

Comment: Does the file contain `NUL` codepoints, or does it contain entities invalid in XML (like `&#0000;`)? In the former case, you can sidestep the issue by creating a `TextReader` that replaces the `NUL` characters with something else before the `XmlTextReader` sees them. If the entities themselves are invalid, that's a little too complicated (but then `CheckCharacters` should have taken care of that). Which class is throwing the exception, though -- `XmlTextReader` or `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: Also, *why* does it contain `NUL` characters, any clue? I'm guessing the file wasn't *produced* by an `XmlSerializer`, or was it?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ondrej Svejdar helped me fixed it, but thank you also to you! :) It was like <element> Blah blah NULL blah blah </element>. I don't know how the file was produced, I just downloaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to reader level instead - subclass `TextReader` class to perform cleanup & fetch it to the `XmlSerializer`.

```
var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
T instance;
using(var cleanupTextReader = new CleanupTextReader(reader)) {
  instance = deserializer.Deserialize(cleanupTextReader);
}
```

Where `CleanupTextReader` is something like:

```
internal sealed class CleanupTextReader : TextReader
{
    private TextReader _in;

    internal CleanupTextReader(TextReader t)
    {
        _in = t;
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        _in.Close();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            ((IDisposable) _in).Dispose();
        }
    }

    public override int Peek()
    {
        return _in.Peek();
    }

    public override int Read()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            var result = _in.Read();
            if (result != '\u0000')
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    private string CleanupString(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.IndexOfAny(new char['\u0000']) < 0)
        {
            return value;
        }
        var builder = new StringBuilder(value.Length);
        foreach (var ch in value)
        {
            if (ch != '\u0000')
            {
                builder.Append(ch);
            }
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    private int CleanupBuffer(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        int adjustedCount = count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            var readIndex = index;
            var writeIndex = index;
            while (readIndex < index + count)
            {
                var ch = buffer[readIndex];
                readIndex++;
                if (ch == '\u0000')
                {
                    adjustedCount--;
                }
                else
                {
                    buffer[writeIndex] = ch;
                    writeIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
        return adjustedCount;
    }

    public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int reallyRead = _in.Read(buffer, index, count);
            if (reallyRead <= 0)
            {
                return reallyRead;
            }

            int cleanRead = CleanupBuffer(buffer, index, reallyRead);
            if (cleanRead != 0)
            {
                return cleanRead;
            }
        }
    }

    public override int ReadBlock(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int reallyRead = _in.ReadBlock(buffer, index, count);
            if (reallyRead <= 0)
            {
                return reallyRead;
            }

            int cleanRead = CleanupBuffer(buffer, index, reallyRead);
            if (cleanRead != 0)
            {
                return cleanRead;
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        return CleanupString(_in.ReadLine());
    }

    public override string ReadToEnd()
    {
        return CleanupString(_in.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Comment: This fails if any call to `Read` ever reads nothing but `NUL` characters, because your method will then return `0`, signaling that there are no more characters.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I passed the StreamReader to the CleanupTextReader and it's working like a magic! :)